# How to measure speed of short piece of C/assembly code?

Tags: c, linux, performance, assembly

Consider this C code:

```
#include <complex.h>
complex float f(complex float x[]) {
  complex float p = 1.0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    p += x[i];
  return p;
}
```

The Intel C Compiler run with `-O3 -march=core-avx2` gives:

```
f:
        vmovups   ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]                       #5.10
        vmovups   ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [64+rdi]                    #5.10
        vmovups   ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [128+rdi]                   #5.10
        vmovups   ymm6, YMMWORD PTR [192+rdi]                   #5.10
        vmovsd    xmm0, QWORD PTR p.152.0.0.1[rip]              #3.19
        vaddps    ymm3, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [32+rdi]              #3.19
        vaddps    ymm4, ymm2, YMMWORD PTR [96+rdi]              #3.19
        vaddps    ymm7, ymm5, YMMWORD PTR [160+rdi]             #3.19
        vaddps    ymm8, ymm6, YMMWORD PTR [224+rdi]             #3.19
        vaddps    ymm9, ymm3, ymm4                              #3.19
        vaddps    ymm10, ymm7, ymm8                             #3.19
        vaddps    ymm11, ymm9, ymm10                            #3.19
        vextractf128 xmm12, ymm11, 1                            #3.19
        vaddps    xmm13, xmm11, xmm12                           #3.19
        vmovhlps  xmm14, xmm13, xmm13                           #3.19
        vaddps    xmm15, xmm13, xmm14                           #3.19
        vaddps    xmm0, xmm15, xmm0                             #3.19
        vzeroupper                                              #6.10
        ret                                                     #6.10
```

gcc version 7 (snapshot) with `-O3 -march=core-avx2 -ffast-math` gives:

```
f:
        lea     r10, [rsp+8]
        and     rsp, -32
        push    QWORD PTR [r10-8]
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        push    r10
        vmovups ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+64]
        vmovaps ymm1, YMMWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+32]
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vmovups ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+128]
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+96]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vmovups ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+192]
        vaddps  ymm1, ymm1, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+160]
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, ymm1
        vaddps  ymm0, ymm0, YMMWORD PTR [rdi+224]
        vunpckhps       xmm3, xmm0, xmm0
        vshufps xmm2, xmm0, xmm0, 255
        vshufps xmm1, xmm0, xmm0, 85
        vaddss  xmm1, xmm2, xmm1
        vaddss  xmm3, xmm3, xmm0
        vextractf128    xmm0, ymm0, 0x1
        vunpckhps       xmm4, xmm0, xmm0
        vshufps xmm2, xmm0, xmm0, 85
        vaddss  xmm4, xmm4, xmm0
        vshufps xmm0, xmm0, xmm0, 255
        vaddss  xmm0, xmm2, xmm0
        vaddss  xmm3, xmm3, xmm4
        vaddss  xmm1, xmm1, xmm0
        vmovss  DWORD PTR [rbp-24], xmm3
        vmovss  DWORD PTR [rbp-20], xmm1
        vzeroupper
        vmovq   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        pop     r10
        pop     rbp
        lea     rsp, [r10-8]
        ret
```

I am interested in which one is faster so it would be great to measure the running time.

However, I don't know how to measure the running time for code that takes so little time.

> Which code is faster and how can one measure it reliably?

Comment: You use this library: https://github.com/google/benchmark

Answer (score 4):

You need a test harness that will call this function a large number of times.

That will get the runtime up to a non-trivial level and will average out any differences caused by OS scheduling.

```
void test_f() 
{
    complex float x[32] = { 1+2i, 2+3i };    // add as many as needed. 
                                             // here i is a special
                                             // constant for complex numbers
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
        f(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't the optimiser eliminate the loop?

Comment: For gcc you can use `__attribute__ ((optimize(0)))` on the test function to prevent it from being optimized.  Alternately, you put the test function in a different .c file compiled with different optimization settings.

Comment: You don't get the assembly in the question if you turn off optimization unless I have misunderstood.  Could you show explicitly how the other solution would work please?

Comment: @eleanora You put your test harness into a file `harness.c` and put the function to test into a file `function.c`. You can compile both files with `-O3` if you like. Then you link the results together without optimizations. That way, the optimizer does not see that calling `f(x)` several times in the test harness is pointless and will not optimize away the loop. However, it will optimize `f()` as best as it can.

Comment: @cmaster That sounds good. Could you add an answer with some command line example so I can accept it?

Comment: @eleanora While I believe that this answer was already good enough (I have upvoted it), I have now formulated a much more comprehensive answer. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Repeat it often enough that it takes a long enough time. Too short makes it more vulnerable to minor timing weirdnesses (the overhead of measuring time at all, instructions jumping over the time-reading instruction either into or out of the effectively timed region thanks to OoOE, whatever), too long .. doesn't really matter unless you're a purist. You can usually guess what the actual time should be, the measured time will be just a bit higher due to interrupts and such but you should get a result that's "near" a sensible value after you adjust for clock speed (for latency measurements you should get an integer number of cycles for example). Do multiple runs and plot it, ignore weird outliers especially at the top.

Ensure that you're in turbo mode (or disable all frequency scaling in the BIOS settings) and that the vector units are "awake" (for AVX code) before timing, so do some warm-ups. The same code that you're intending to time can do that.

Be very careful that you deliberately choose either to make the iterations dependent (measuring latency) or independent (measuring throughput), don't just do something random - you'd have a measurement that you don't know is latency or throughput. Also don't let the compiler optimize it away some or all calls to the thing you're measuring so you end up measuring *nothing*.

You can use `rdtscp` for the timing itself, or something less precise - the less precision the longer your timing loop needs to be. You can roughly tell the precision from how the plot looks, if it looks highly discrete with a few "bins" that everything lines up in, use more iterations (or a better time measurement).

If you intend to measure under specific cache conditions it gets trickier, because setting up that state requires time too, so it turns a bit into a game of "guess the overhead" (which is hard to measure exactly).

FWIW the ICC asm looks faster, GCC is doing a lot of scalar math.

Comment: How do you avoid the optimiser eliminating the loop if you just repeat it?

Comment: @eleanora you can put the function in a different compilation unit (and then don't use LTO) (then it has to be called in a loop since the optimizer has to assume the function might do something funny), or just write the loop in assembly and be super sure that it does exactly what you want

Comment: Would you be able to show the code needed for those ideas?  If it's possible to add the loop in assembly that looks like best solution but I don't know how to mix C and assembly.

Comment: @eleanora I could show some example, but it depends on platform details (and the assembler). Combining C and assembly is not hard though, just compile/assembly into object files and link them together with the linker as usual. Calling a C function from assembly needs the right name (probably you need an underscore before the function name) and some form of `extern` declaration (syntax differs between assemblers)

Comment: Thank you. I am on linux and am happy to use any tool that is most convenient for you. I think the assembly I pasted should compile/assembe with `gas` for example.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you need to do whenever you want to perform a performance measurement:

1. Repeat the operation to be measured often enough to get up to times that you can measure accurately. Usually one to ten seconds are enough. This can be achieved by a simple loop in virtually all cases.
2. Prevent the optimizer from optimizing out the repetitions or optimizing the measured operation out entirely due to its unused results.

   There are several possible approaches to this:

   - Modify the input in every iteration and actually use all the results. In your case, this could look something like this:

     ```
     complex float accu = 0+0i;
     for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
         x[i%32] += 42+3i;   //different input on each pass
         accu += f(x);
     }
     printComplex(accu);    //this depends on the output of all passes
     ```

     Note that this approach is a bit difficult to use, because it's very easy to overlook an optimization possibility and fail to safeguard against it. Your optimizer may understand the effects of too simple input modifications, and compile out significant parts of `f()` anyway, so be careful. The upside of this is that it allows the optimizer to inline the function, avoiding the function call overhead.
   - Split into independent compilation units: Put the repetition loop into one .c file, and put the function to be tested into another .c file. Compile both separately with full optimizations, and link without optimizations.

     That way, the optimizer cannot look into your function when it compiles the repetition loop, and thus cannot know whether it has sideeffects. As such, it cannot optimize away the repetition. Likewise, when it compiles the function to be tested, it does not know that its results are not used, and consequently cannot optimize its body away entirely. The linker then just connects the parts.

     The downside of this is, that you cannot get the function call overhead out of the measurement. This may necessitate a reference measurement along the lines of point 3.
   - Use some compiler directives like `#pragma` or `__attribute__(())` to avoid harmful optimizations. I have never used this, as either of the two approaches above has served me well in all cases, but it is certainly an option. The details are compiler specific, though.
3. Assess the overhead of the measurement itself. If you are measuring high-latency operations like I/O calls, you may be able to skip this, but if you are measuring fast stuff like CPU arithmetic as in your example, you should run a comparison test where you define your function as

   ```
   complex float f(complex float x[]) {
       complex float p = 1.0;
       return p;
   }
   ```

Comment: How do you compile  with full optimizations but link without optimizations?

Comment: You simply use `gcc -O3` when compiling, and use `gcc` when linking. The linker will usually just treat the symbols created during compiling as black boxes. However, afaik, there are some link-time optimizations that can be switched on explicitly. Just don't specify these to the linker command and you should be fine.